# Error 500: layout "pagename" not found joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I need joomla and php  expert help.I have just purchased joombri freelance theme which is built in joomla. I want to rename the existing php files like "escrow.php" etc but when i change the name of the file from cpanel then the page link doesn't work. it gives error 500 "layout pagename not found".Please give me the solution of problem.Thanks in advance

Regards
hussain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens because you've changed the name of the files so the theme can no longer find those files that it needs.

The solution is to rename the files to how they were originally when you installed the component.